# What has happened to ComboBox.Sorted := True; in Delphi 10.2?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Having recently received a 'Tumbleweed' badge for my last question, I am not sure whether I should be asking any more questions, but here goes.

I am populating a `TComboBox` with items from a sqlite table and this works fine.  In my previous version of Delphi I was able to use `ComboBox1.Sorted := True;` to sort the items, but this seems to have disappeared in Delphi 10.2.  I can sort the items in the table by applying a query and then populate the `TComboBox` from the sorted table.  However, for curiosities sake I would like to find out how one now sorts items in a `TComboBox`.  I have found some references to `TComboBox(Sort:Compare)` but have not succeeded in getting this to work to as of yet.

Can somebody please shed some light on this - many thanks

Comment: VCL or Firemonkey?

Comment: Both VCL and Firemonkey at the moment - thanks

Comment: I have tested `TComboBox` with different numbers as items and seems it had sorted them perfectly.

Comment: I have TCombobox.Sorted property in 10.2.3...

Comment: VCL stilll has it: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox.Sorted. FMX - maybe - never has it, can't find it in XE7 e.g..

Comment: Thank you all - having just tested on a basic VCL form with ComboBox, indeed the sorted property is there.  However it still begs the question how does one sort a ComboBox using Firemonkey ?

Comment: Do you have access to the sources of VCL? You obviously could look at implementation of sort algorithm in `TComboBox` and adapt it for FMX.

Comment: I do have access Dima.  I will look later today and see what I can do.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Glad to hear it, because I use Delphi Starter so I have no source code and cannot check sort algorithm myself. And one else note, WobblyBob, if you are writing a comment to someone consider use *@* sign to notify user you are writing to.

Comment: @Dima: why don't you get Delphi Tokyo Community Edition? Comes even with source, AFAIK. https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter/free-download (the link name is slightly misleading: this is not the old Starter).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, thank you! I will check this out right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firemonkey you can populate a `TComboBox` instance either simply with the `Items` property of type `TStrings` or you add `TListBoxItem` instances with the form designer. But internally always `TListBoxItem` for the elements is used.

To use the `TComboBox.Sort` you need to provide an anonymous compare-function.

This is a simple example usage of `TComboBox.Sort`

```
cbxItems.Sort(
  function (pLeft, pRight: TFMXObject): Integer
  var
    lLeft, lRight: TListBoxItem;
  begin
    lLeft := TListBoxItem(pLeft);
    lRight := TListBoxItem(pRight);
    Result := String.Compare(lLeft.Text, lRight.Text);
  end
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly !!  Brilliant !!